# C# - getting value of SelectedItem in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem

I have a simple Windows Forms application (with an Access database) with a combobox (cmbStores) that is populated in the most simple way imaginable.

**Problem**: I am unable to get the value of the selected item.

Here is how I am populating this combobox:

```
// Variable declaration
        string strQueryStores = "SELECT StoreNumber FROM tblStoresAndRegion ORDER BY StoreNumber";
        string strConnectionString = UtilityClass.GetConnectionString();
        OleDbConnection connStores;
        OleDbDataReader readerStores = null;

        connStores = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);

        try
        {
            connStores.Open();
            OleDbCommand sqlGetStores = new OleDbCommand(strQueryStores, connStores);

            cmbStore.Items.Clear();
            cmbStore.Items.Add("All");
            if (connStores != null)
            {
                readerStores = sqlGetStores.ExecuteReader();

                if (readerStores.HasRows)
                {
                    while (readerStores.Read())
                    {
                        cmbStore.Items.Add (Convert.ToInt32(readerStores["StoreNumber"]));
                    }
                }
            }
            cmbStore.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }

        catch (OleDbException oledblEX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(oledblEX.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (readerStores != null)
                readerStores.Close();
            if (connStores != null)
                connStores.Close();
        }
```

This is how I am trying to get the value of the selected item.

```
int nStoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbABSM.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Where is the code you're using to get the selected item?  Are you getting an exception? Incorrect value?  What is happening when you try  to get the selected item?

Comment: You get some inconsistency in your code. You fill the _cmdStore_ box, and try to read the _cmbABSM_ box. Is it really the case, or you just mistyped?

Comment: @Matzi ... I mistyped here. The code should be int nStoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbStore.SelectedItem);

Comment: Solved (but still confused) ... When i use this code, int nStoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbStore.Text); it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I am a little late, but this works well:

```
int? nStoreNumber = cmbABSM.SelectedValue as int?;
if (nStoreNumber==null)
    return;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `SelectedValue` if `ValueMember` is set for the combobox, otherwise default to the `Text` property:

```
//If ValueMember is set
int nStoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbABSM.SelectedValue);

//Otherwise
int nStoreNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cmbABSM.Text);
```

Either way I would recommend you make sure the value of what is selected is a valid `int`.

```
int nStoreNumber;

if (!int.TryParse(cmbABSM.SelectedValue, out nStoreNumber))
{
    //This is not a valid number.  Notify the user.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

does

```
Int32.Parse(box.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

work for you?

Comment: You should really use either the `Value` or the `Text` property on the item.  It is not clear to the reader which is returned by `ToString`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SelectedItem.Value or SelectedValue, the practical difference is in what they return when there is no selection.

SelectedItem.Value returns the value, will return null if there is no selected item.

SelectedValue also returns the value, but will return an empty string if there is no selected item

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx